# How to track crashing of window form?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to track window form crashing ? Like any event is called or anything else is called or we can track that window form is crashed ? Like dispose is called window form is crashed. But anything else which is happened so we can track out crashing of window form ?

Like problem is I have one window application    on that there is tutorial balloon on the main form which moves for each control on the main form and describes the application functionality by indicating control on the main form one by one. And each time balloon moves balloon is disposes and new balloon form is created.

Now I want to insert the step number in the database when that balloon was crashed. I cannot understand what should I do ? What is happened when that balloon window(window form) is crashed ? There is a dispose event which is occurred but  it is happened  each time balloon creates so is there any thing else to track crashing ?

EDIT: Sorry to all, I forgot to specify that it is with .net framework 2.0.

Comment: Do you really mean `crashed` or is it when the balloon is `closed`? I think you want to track whenever one balloon closes and log it somewhere so that you don't have to show that part of tutorial again. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Program.cs file, place a try/catch block inside the Main() function. The idea is to have the Application.Run(*yourformhere*) inside such a block. Then inside the catch you can probably manage to save some state (like the step at which the balloon crashed the form) in the DB. Good Luck!

Comment: but in the project of that balloon window form there is no main() function.

Comment: Try putting the try/catch in **YOUR** app's Main() function.

Answer (score 5):

Use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx

If any undhandled exception occurs in a forms thread, it will get here. If it's null, you get the usual dialog (undhandled exception occurred, you can continue or close, and see the stack trace).

Comment: In lieu of using an attached debugger, this is a good idea.  Just be sure that your app is running with administrative privileges or the EventLog.CreateEventSource in the MSDN sample itself will raise an exception.

Comment: Yes of course, why not? The fundamentals of winforms never change.

Answer (score 3):

This is an excerpt from a small Windows Forms 2.0 program of mine:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Application.ThreadException +=
        applicationThreadException;

    // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms 
    // errors to go through our handler.
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(
        UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
        currentDomainUnhandledException;

    ...
}
```

With the two handlers

```
private static void currentDomainUnhandledException(
    object sender,
    UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    handleException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}
```

and

```
private static void applicationThreadException(
    object sender,
    ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    handleException(e.Exception);
}
```

The actual function to handle the exceptions does in my example:

```
private static void handleException(
    Exception exception)
{
    LogCentral.Current.LogError(
        @"Exception occurred.",
        exception);

    if (ErrorForm.IsErrorFormShowing)
    {
        LogCentral.Current.LogInfo(
            @"Error form already showing, not showing again.",
            exception);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var form = new ErrorForm(exception))
        {
            var result = form.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.Abort)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. it logs the error via [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) and then displays an error form to show the user further information (exception message) and allow to quit the application.